# convert 3d coordinates to 2d screen coordinates (plane mesh)

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Hello I have a plane in three.js with width 5000 and height 5000. With the following code I convert 3d coordinates into 2d, more specific I get the top left point of the plane and the bottom right.
I initialize my camera with position x: 0, y: 0, z: 70000 and rotation x:0,y:0,z:0.

The coordinates I get if I don't rotate my camera (using orbit controls) are correct:

[image]

however if I rotate my camera the coordinates are not correct and I cant figure out why.
Here is my code so far:

```
var vec3 = new THREE.Vector3();
    vec3.set( _that.model.position.x - 2500, _that.model.position.y + 2500, _that.model.position.z ); // top left corner
    vec3.project( _that.vise.camera );

var percX = Math.abs(vec3.x + 1) / 2;
var percY = Math.abs(-vec3.y + 1) / 2;

this.topLeft = {
    x : percX * _that.vise.options.generic.container.clientWidth,
    y : percY * _that.vise.options.generic.container.clientHeight
}

var vec4 = new THREE.Vector3();
    vec4.set( _that.model.position.x + 2500, _that.model.position.y - 2500, _that.model.position.z ); // top left corner
    vec4.project( _that.vise.camera );

var percX = Math.abs(vec4.x + 1) / 2;
var percY = Math.abs(-vec4.y + 1) / 2;

this.bottomRight = {
    x : percX * _that.vise.options.generic.container.clientWidth,
    y : percY * _that.vise.options.generic.container.clientHeight
}

this.projectedVector = {
    x : Math.abs(this.topLeft.x - this.bottomRight.x),
    y : Math.abs(this.topLeft.y - this.bottomRight.y)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this:

http://www.threejsgames.com/extensions/#threex.objcoord

It includes a translation of 3D to Screen Position, is this what you want?

Comment: unless I'm doing something wrong... I've tried using this extension

Comment: Check out your console, there some changes so you have to Update this.